# SQL Server unique constraint failing to discard duplicate record

Tags: sql-server

I am adding a constraint on multiple column in one the table of my SQL Server database.

Below is the query to add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [db].[tablename] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [contact_uniq_constraint] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([account_id_fk] ASC, [contact_type] ASC,
                             [contact] ASC, [country_code] ASC)
                      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                            SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                            ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                            ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

But I am still able to add duplicate in the table. Can someone help me identify the reason?

[image: Table with duplicates]

Comment: This checks for uniqueness across all values in those columns meaning they must all match. If you *are* aware of that then please include an [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Works fine for me: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5db9a962b16cdf6f17d2c226abf9f9b)

Comment: missing `CREATE TABLE` statement, and `INSERT` values to reproduce

Comment: @Igor, I have provided table with duplicate data where this constraint is already set.

Comment: Read my 1st comment. A unique index looks at the combination of **all** the columns provided. So the value of `account_id_fk` **AND** `contact_type` **AND** `contact` **AND** `country_code` must be the some across 1 or more records for the constraint to invalidate a record.

Comment: Check the last two tuples, they have the same value for above four columns.

Comment: I will have to take your word for it, that this constraint has been applied to your table. You need to include an [mcve] that illustrates the problem. A screen shot of values can't be tested or validated

Comment: Most likely there are nonprintable chars in the char columns, just convert them to binary to find the differences (for the "duplicate" tuples).